# Update facet fields together with ordinary fields in Haystack/SOLR

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, django-celery

I'm using Django-Haystack with Solr on backend and CelerySignalProcessor. It's all right, but when I update some field, all my index gets updated, but if I call facet_count(), then I will get old data. However, I gets latest data from filter() method. I think, this is because of additional {name}_exact field that Haystack uses for faceted fields. Am I right? If so, how can I force signal processor to update both fields?